# Project not appearing after adding cocoapods - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have been working on an xcode project for iPad/iPhone and need to add networking. So I went through the usual steps of generating the .xcworkspace using my terminal and the necessary podfile to include AFNetworking dependencies.

I created all the pod "stuff" on my desktop and then dragged all those files into the folder containing my original xcode project.  I then opened the workspace assuming that both the pods and the original project would show on the left (so 2 projects).

The pod "stuff" seems to be there fine but the project is red.  So there is nothing to build.

Attached is a screenshot. Note the red project in the upper left corner.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: Actually you should not add any files mannually...that is where you were misleading..have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so I just made a new project and this time added cocoa pods first. It seems to only be problem when you try adding adding cocoa pods midway through a project.